# Como logro hacer que mis dropzones funcionen de manera correcta para cada tipo de archivo con vue y laravel, que se vea como el primer apartado

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-9

Quiero que en cada uno de mis dropzones, que al momento que le de click, pueda subir archivos en cada uno, mostre el index y solo me sirvio para la primera tipo de categoria que tengo pero para los demas no, ¿Como consigo que se vea igual a la primera parte?

[image: Este es mi problema]

Mi componente que contiene el dropzone en el cual quiero que funcione correctamente

```
<template>
    <div class="container cont">
  
      <div class="row">
  
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
  
          <input type="text" v-model="buscar" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar por nombre de archivo" />
  
        </div>

        <div class="p-3 bg-secondary card border-radius-xl js-active position-relative mx-auto my-5 col-12 col-lg-8" data-animation="FadeIn" v-for="categoria in categorias" :key="categoria.id">
                <div class="text-center row">
                    <div class="mx-auto col-10">
                        <h5 class="font-weight-normal">
                         <h1 class="text-white">{{ categoria.name }}</h1>
                            <div class="row mt-4 mb-4">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div v-for="tipo in categoria.tipo_categoria" :key="tipo.id" class="text-white text-sm">
                                        <h3 class="text-white text-xl"> {{ tipo.name }}</h3>
                                            <small class="text-primary mr-6 text-white" v-for="(archivo, index) in tipo.archivo" :key="archivo.id">
                                                 {{ archivo.nombre }}
                                                <Dropzone :id="index"/>
                                            </small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="multisteps-form__content">
                    <div class="mt-3 row"></div>
                    <div class=""></div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
<script>

  import Dropzone from '../../Pages/Expedientes/Dropzone.vue';
  
  export default {
    components: {
      Dropzone
    },
    name: 'Categorias',
    props: {
      msg: String,
      categorias: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
      }
    },
    methods: {
  
    },
    mounted: function () {
      console.log("Time");
    },
  
    // declaro el elemento buscar 
    data() {
      return {
        buscar: ''
      }
    },
  
    // Creo un método llamado 'items' y obtengo los datos de los pokemones
    // Asimismo filtro la búsqueda de los pokemones con el método filter()  
    computed: {
      categorias() {
        return this.categorias.filter(categoria => {
          return categoria.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.buscar.toLowerCase());
        });
      },
  
    }
  
  }
  
  </script>
```

Como ven aqui tengo mi dropzone; este seria el codigo de mi dropzone con el cual voy a subir los archivos al servidor

```
<template>
  <div class="multisteps-form__content">
    <div class="mt-3 row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <form
          :id="id"
          action="/file-upload"
          class="form-control dropzone"
        >
          <div class="fallback">
            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

  <script>
  import ArgonButton from "@/components/ArgonButton.vue";
  import Dropzone from "dropzone";

  export default {
    props: {

    },
    name: "Media",
    props: {
        id: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    components: {
      ArgonButton,
    },
    mounted() {
      // Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;
      
      var drop = document.getElementById(this.id);
      new Dropzone(drop, {
        url: "/file/post",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
      });
    },
  };
  </script>
```

Agradeceria bastante si alguien puede guiarme de manera correcta, estoy trabajando con vue 3 y laravel en su version 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he resuelto con una funcion de math random de JS como se muestra:

```
<small class="text-primary mr-6 text-white" v-for="(archivo, index) in tipo.archivo" :key="archivo.id">
                     {{ archivo.nombre }}
                       <Dropzone :id="Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8)"/>
</small>
```